# Why changing the prototype does not affect previously created objects?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following code:

```
var A = function() {};
var a = new A();
var b = new A();
A.prototype.member1 = 10;

A.prototype = {}
var c = new A();
console.log(a.member1);
console.log(a.constructor === b.constructor);
console.log(a.constructor === c.constructor);
console.log('---------');
console.log(c.member1);
```

It's output is:

```
10
true
false
---------
undefined
undefined
```

The prototype of `a` and `b` has not changed and `c` had a new one. Am i right that this was caused by the fact that `a.constructor` is not equal to `c.constructor` and each of them had own `prototype`? Are there any other circs when constructors of two objects might not be equal?

Extra question: why there were printed two `undefined` strings? (Chromium)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected ;)

Comment: Are you in Chrome? If so, the `console.log(undefined)` will log two things: the logged `undefined` and the returned `undefined`.

Comment: For the record, you can differentiate between them by the grayish arrow to the left :)

Comment: Can someone please explain why `c.construtor` now is pointing to `object`? Isn't it supposed to be a function? and more specifically, should it be function `A`? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is invalid. `console.log(a.member1);` outputting `10` indicates that changing the prototype does affect previously created objects (i.e. `a`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time you're calling

```
var a = new A();
```

basically this assignment is done:

```
a.__proto__ = A.prototype;
```

Then you reassign the `A.prototype` to a new object, so `c` gets `{}` as its prototype.

```
A.prototype = {};
var c = new A();
```

However, this doesn't destroy the old `A.prototype` object - `a.__proto__` is still pointing to it.

> Am i right that this was caused by the fact that a.constructor is not equal to c.constructor and each of them had own prototype?

`.constructor` is basically just a convenience property. It has no effect on how instances behave.

> Extra question: why there were printed two undefined strings?

Not in my console, they don't! (Opera 12)

Answer (score 2):

When you create an object, the prototype of the constructor is assigned to the `__proto__` property of the new object.  You're then changing the prototype, but the two `a` and `b` objects are already pointing at the original reference:

```
var a = new A();
// a.__proto__ == A.prototype == {} (soon == {member1:10})
var b = new A();
// b.__proto__ == A.prototype == {} (soon == {member1:10})

A.prototype = {} // this changes A.prototype, but not a.__proto__ or b.__proto__
var c = new A(); // c.__proto__ = {}
```

your first `undefined` is from `c.member1`.  The 2nd one is chrome saying your entire statement had no return value

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in this line of your code:

```
A.prototype = {}
```

When you get to this line of code, you are actually creating a BRAND NEW OBJECT in memory that is {}. Creating any new objects using A as your constructor will point to this BRAND NEW OBJECT as the prototype.

However, the OLD PROTOTYPE still exists in memory. It's just that A.prototype no longer points to it. Any objects you create using A as the constructor before you redefine A's prototype reference are still pointing to this OLD PROTOTYPE as it's prototype.