# Chaining prototypes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, prototype

I wonder why based on my code, cat.getIt(); won't work. I created two objects and wanted the "cat" object to have the "dog" object as its prototype. It worked but what doesn't work is the dogs method "getIt" won't get inherited by the object cat even though I said:  Cat.prototype=new Dog() (Cat.prototype=Object.create(Dog.prototype); didn't work too). Does anyone know why?

```
function Dog (name){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=[];
}
var myDog= new Dog("Jo");

Dog.prototype.sayHi=function(){
return "My name is " + this.name + ", I'm a Dog";

};

Dog.prototype.getIt = function(){

var small = {
    name: "Baby " + this.name   
};

this.age = [small];
return small;
}
myDog.getIt();


function Cat(name,color){

Dog.call(this,name);
this.color=color;
}
var cat = new Cat("Lexy", "red");

//Cat.prototype=Object.create(Dog.prototype); //Or should I do it like that?
Cat.prototype=new Dog();

cat.getIt();
```

Comment: If you're replacing the `prototype` (vs modifying it), do that *before* creating instances. Otherwise, the instances will remember the previous `prototype` object.

Comment: Thanks! It worked now! I actually thought, if I created cat and then set the Cats prototype to Dog- it would be okay because usually you can create an object using the constructor function and AFTERWARDS set a prototype and the instances will still have access to the properties etc of the newly created prototype. Why is that not true in this case?

Comment: Sorry. `Cat.prototype = new Dog();` is what I was referring to. This assigns a new object, an instance of `Dog`, as the `Cat.prototype`. To use that object, you'll want to change the order of these statements – `Cat.prototype = new Dog(); var cat = new Cat("Lexy", "red");`.

Comment: In the case of `Dog` itself, the object remains the same, which is why the order doesn't affect it. It's only gaining new properties – `Dog.prototype.sayHi`, etc.

Comment: Oh its 2 different things to 1: create a prototype that applies to the Object created BEFORE OR!! chain a objects prototype of the one of another object?

Comment: What I mean is: function Dog (name){
 this.name=name;
 this.age=[];
}
var myDog= new Dog("Jo");

Dog.prototype.sayHi=function(){
 return "My name is " + this.name + ", I'm a Dog";
 
}; // here I also created the object "myDog" and AFTERWARDS I set the property and that was alright. However in the cat case, its not alright and I have to set the prototype before I create cat.

Comment: Correct. For some additional details: [Why changing the prototype does not affect previously created objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080434/why-changing-the-prototype-does-not-affect-previously-created-objects)

Comment: Okay thank you! just an additional question: If I wanted to override the Dog prototype method getIt with a new getIt method-my code works except for cat.age -here Im getting [] which is what the Dog constructor function had-what am I doing wrong?
Cat.prototype.getIt=function(color){
 var baby = {
  name: "Baby " + this.name,
  color:color,
  age: this.name+this.color
 }
 return baby;
 };